# Track page views

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageviews

I am looking for a C# code which tracks number of times a  page is visited by unique users (as like tracking IP address) per day and display it to my site.

Apart from using Google Analytics, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: One easy way to track pageviews with a custom implementation is with an HttpModule. Here's an article on how to write one: http://madskristensen.net/post/track-your-visitors-using-an-httpmodule